# Posted objects in RequestTemplate end up having null fields once they reach the RestController

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-web

I am trying to save a domain object via my REST api from within another Spring MVC application using RestTemplate. It successfully makes the call to the api, but the `foo` and `bar` fields of TheThing object end up being null once it reaches the rest controller

from TheThingController in the MVC app

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(Model model) {
    TheThing theThing = new TheThing();
    theThing.setFoo("foo");
    theThing.setBar("bar");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    TheThing savedThing = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8090/theThing", theThing, TheThing.class);
    return "thingForm";
}
```

TheThingRestController

```
@RestController
public class TheThingRestController {

    @Autowired
    private TheThingMapper theThingMapper; 

    @RequestMapping(path = "/theThing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(TheThing theThing) {
        theThingMapper.createTheThing(theThing); // theThing isn't null, but all of its fields are
    }
}
```

Somehow the fields of TheThing object are getting lost in translation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just needed to Add the `@RequestBody` annotation to TheThing method parameter in the RestController